# rstudio grep using 2 conditions

Tags: r

Using Rstudio 1.0.153 (in OSX Sierra)

Hi, 
I want use the function grep and regular expressions to return all strings that start with FA_* and end in Sc

One condition starting with FA*: `grep("^FA_",names(nc_df), value=TRUE)` works. Also, ending with *Sc also works. `grep("*Sc$",names(nc_df), value=TRUE)`. But both condition do not work ( `grep("^FA_*Sc$",names(nc_df), value=TRUE)` )!

How can I use both in the same line of code?

Thanks,
Rodrigo

Comment: Both commands separately give me a list of what I need but not together. I wanted to include the output here but Stackoverflow doesn't allow me (it gives me an indent error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep("^FA.*Sc$", names(nc_df), value = TRUE)
```

You were very close! You have to add `.*` (dot) for multiple characters.